# PHP: CURL library: Getting status of curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL in PHP to write a function to get a remote xml file into my local folder. Everything works fine however I have a question:

```
  $fileIn = curl_init("http://some-remote-host.com/file.xml);
  $fileOut = fopen('myLocal.xml", "w");

  curl_setopt($fileIn, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileOut);
  curl_setopt($fileIn, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  $isCopied = curl_exec($fileIn);
  curl_close($fileIn);
  fclose($fileOut);

  if(!$isCopied)
     return false;
  else
     //do something else
```

Based on the documentation I read, $isCopied is supposed to be false when the remote file does not exist, and there shouldn't be myLocal.xml but my `if(!$isCopied)` doesn't seem tobe working. And this is the content of my myLocal.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL something.xml was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at somehost.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

My question is: How to get a boolean variable telling me when it succeeded and when it did not. (means when the remote file doesn not exist).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
curl_getinfo($fileIn, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

to see what http code was returned (you're looking for 200).

Comment: Did you print it just after curl_exec($fileIn);? If so, please try using curl_errno($ch) to see if you got any errors (also: var_dump is better for debugging than simple echo)

Comment: That's weird. The curl_getinfo is always 0 :(

Comment: No. I used it after curl_init. Where should I use it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> $isCopied = curl_getinfo($fileIn,
>   CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 404;

Comment: I'm afraid accepting ANY other http code value than 404 is not a good idea, for example http 500 represents server error.