# Catch 404 error on DOMDocument->load()

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

I am loading a bunch of rss feeds using DOM and sometimes one will 404 instead of producing the file.  The problem is that the web-server sends out an html 404 page in place of the expected xml file so using this code:

```
$rssDom = new DOMDocument();
$rssDom->load($url);
$channel = $rssDom->getElementsByTagName('channel');
$channel = $channel->item(0);
$items = $channel->getElementsByTagName('item');
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Entity 'nbsp' not defined
```

Followed by this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object
```

Normally, this code works fine, but on the occasion that I get a 404 it fails to do anything.  I tried a standard try-catch around the load statement but it doesn't seem to catch it.

Comment: If "Entity nbsp; is not defined", perhaps the 404 returned an XML (not HTML) source? (`&nbsp;` is not defined in XML.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [suppress the output of parsing errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) with

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

To check whether the returned response is a 404 you can check the [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) after the call to `DOMDocument::load()`

Example:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$rssDom = new DOMDocument();
$rssDom->load($url);
if (strpos($http_response_header[0], '404')) {
    die('file not found. exiting.');
}
```

The alternative would be to use `file_get_contents` and then check the response header and if its not a 404 load the markup with `DOMDocument::loadXml`. This would prevent `DOMDocument` from parsing invalid XML.

Note that all this assumes that the server correctly returns a 404 header in the response.

Comment: +1, although I think I preferred it when I didn't know about `$http_response_headers` at all. PHP, how low can you go?

Comment: @Jon yeah, I'd prefer to have a function like `get_last_response_headers()` instead of `$http_response_headers` magically populating after an http call. it's so unobvious.

Comment: Typo? `$http_response_headers` is not defined, while `$http_response_header` is defined thou. The doc page [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) linked to the singular `header` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Load the HTML manually with `file_get_contents` or `curl` (which allows you to do your own error checks) and if all goes well then feed the results to [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

There are lots of `curl` examples here (e.g. look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552318/php-curl-library-getting-status-of-curl-exec), although it's surely not the best); to get the HTTP status code you would use [`curl_getinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php).

Comment: I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4358138/2257664) to check the HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the warning, you could use [`LIBXML_NOWARNING`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) (note: suppressing warnings normally isn't a good thing to do).

the more important problem here is the fatal error: to avoid this, you should check if the document has been loaded correctly. to to this, just save the [`load()`s return-value](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) and ise it:

```
$loaded = $rssDom->load($url, LIBXML_NOWARNING);
if($loaded){
    $channel = $rssDom->getElementsByTagName('channel');
    $channel = $channel->item(0);
    $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName('item');
}else{
    // show error-message or something like that
}
```

Comment: The problem is that load thinks it succeeded, so it does not stay false.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$rssDom = new DOMDocument();
if($rssDom->load($url)) {
   $channel = $rssDom->getElementsByTagName('channel');
   $channel = $channel->item(0);
   $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName('item');
}
```

Comment: As I said above, the problem is that load thinks it succeeded, so it does not stay false.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs a solution, this works like charm:

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$loaded=@$objDOM->load(url);

if (!$loaded){
    //something went terribly wrong
} else {
    //this is going ok!!
}
```

This works as we supress warnings by '@' and load returns true or false in case of errors.